# What's the difference between Literal and Union in Python typing?

Tags: python, typing

What's the difference between `Literal` and `Union` in Python typing?

I can't see any difference between them.
Could anyone explain this?

My IDE didn't respond to me when I use like `Union[2,3]`.

Comment: Can you provide an example where both Literal and Union can be used? Also checkout [literal definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) - they look completely different

Comment: What similarities do you see? Maybe you can explain how you understand each, because they are two very different things.

Comment: Aside from `Literal['one', 'two']` being shorthand for `Union[Literal['one'], Literal['two']]` (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#shortening-unions-of-literals), it's hard to see why you perceive no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Union[x, y]` means ["either `x` or `y`"](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Union). `Literal[5, 6]` means ["literally `5` or literally `6`"](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) (not some variable that's equal to any of those, but *literally* `5` or `6`).

The difference is that the arguments of `Union` *must be types*. The arguments to `Literal` are *literals*. Type names (like `int`, `float`, `MyClass`) are not literals (but they do represent types), so they can't be used in `Literal`. Literals (like `5`, `'Hello!'` and `[1,2,3]`) are not types, so they cannot be used in `Union`.

For example, these types are not correct:

```
Literal[str, float]  # none of the arguments are literals
Union[5, 6] # none of the arguments are types
```

---

In response to your comment, `None` is *both* a literal and a type.

`None` is defined as a literal in [Python's grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html):

```
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [testlist_comp] ']' | # maybe list literal
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' | # maybe dict/set literal
       NAME |  # NOT a literal
       NUMBER | # int/float literal
       STRING+ | # string literal
       '...' | # Ellipsis literal
       'None' | # None literal!
       'True' | 'False')
```

Here, `None` is a literal, thus, it can be used in `Literal`. However, it's *not* a class:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.isclass(None)
False
>>> inspect.isclass(5)
False
>>> inspect.isclass(str)
True
```

So, it can't be used in `Union`. **BUT** it actually *is* used in `Union`: `Union[str, None]` means "type `str` or *nothing*". From the docs on `Union`:

> You can use `Optional[X]` as a shorthand for `Union[X, None]`

Comment: Tanks for your explanation!
Now I got it.But what about the None?
Cloud it show in Literal or Union?Or both?

Answer (score 0):

Literal: The Literal type is used when you want to specify that a variable can only have certain specific values. It's like setting a strict rule. For example, if you declare a variable as Literal['red', 'green', 'blue'], it means the variable is allowed to be 'red', 'green', or 'blue' and nothing else. It is a way to limit the value to a few predefined options.

Union: Union is used when a variable can belong to more than one type. It’s like giving multiple choices. For example, if you use Union[int, str], it means the variable can either be an integer or a string. It is useful when a variable can reasonably be of several different types.